# R using getURL data to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rcurl

I'm downloading data from the web but then don't know how to change it to a dataframe or anything useful. Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
library(RCurl) 
myfile = getURL(http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/lister_ul.dat,
ssl.verifyhost=FALSE, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

If I use this:

```
A = read.csv(textConnection(myfile), header = F)
```

then R understands this:

```
c("1 1 1")
```

as the first row and not this:

```
c(1, 1, 1).
```

This doesn't work b/c I need to use

```
colnames(A) = c("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

and can't find a workaround that doesn't involve some tedious work using

```
unlist(strsplit(A))
```

Ughh!!

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Or maybe I'll write my own tedious function, if necessary.

gwynn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Since I don't have `RCurl` installed but I do have `httr` (which uses `curl`), I'll start with that. It's a moot problem, though, since I get to the same table-looking content as you.

Also, @udden2903's answer is more straight-forward, I'm making an assumption that this is a simplified problem, and that you may have need to continue using an alternative fetching method that `read.table(URL)` does not allow. (To continue using `httr` and support some other things such as authentication, read its documentation.)

```
library(httr)
myfile = GET("http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/lister_ul.dat")
str(content(myfile))
# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#  chr "1 1  1\n1 0 11\n0 1  6\n0 0  6\n"
```

So, `content(myfile)` is now what your `myfile` is. The first trick is that your data is not comma-delimited ("csv"), so using `read.table` is necessary. Second, you nede to specifiy that the first line is not headers.

```
x <- read.table(textConnection(content(myfile, encoding = "UTF-8")), header = FALSE)
x
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  1  0 11
# 3  0  1  6
# 4  0  0  6
```

Now just assign your headers.

```
colnames(x) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
x
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    1    0   11
# 3    0    1    6
# 4    0    0    6
```

Comment: The same methodology doesn't work for this url: ""http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/warpeace.dat."  I can download it with getURL but then not sure what to do from there. I'm trying to download all of the datasets from http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/datasets.html and turn it into a GUI. I parsed the html code but can't quite read the data. Any suggestions?

Comment: That link fails for two reasons: (1) your link includes an extra dot resulting in a HTTP-404, easily removed; and (2) it is fixed-width and not space-delimited. You may prefer to use the [`readr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html) package, since it handles this type of thing more smoothly. Instead you would use `readr::read_table(content(myfile, encoding="UTF-8"), col_names=FALSE)`. Otherwise, consider fixed-width table parsing with [`read.fwf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html), a bit more more literal and fragile but works fine.

Comment: The extra "." is the result of poor editing. 

This worked until "http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/crop_circle.csv" probably because it's a csv file. I have dat, csv, lsx, and xls. I'll need to do them all separately. For the xls I'm using read_excel. What should I do with the csv and lsx? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Of course it won't work with `crop_circle.csv`: `read.csv` reads comma-delimited files, `read.table` for other formats of tables stored in a file. If by "lsx" you actually mean "xlsx" (since I found no files ending in `.lsx`), then your choice of `readxl::read_excel` should work equally for both. For each link you harvest, you will need to determine by the file extension which parsing function you'll need to use.

Comment: I'm a bit tired, so I might misunderstand, but is this the function I'm to use for a csv file: readr::read_csv(content(myfile, encoding="UTF-8"), col_names=FALSE)? Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Yes, that's the function call for CSV files.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
df <- read.table('http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/lister_ul.dat')
```

Comment: Also this ^ haha

Comment: If all I wanted to do was read that one webpage I'm sure it would've. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Using only base package functions:

```
as.data.frame(
    do.call("rbind", strsplit(
        readLines("http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/lister_ul.dat"),
        "\\s+"))
)

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1
2  1  0 11
3  0  1  6
4  0  0  6
```

What we did was read the raw lines from the webpage, then split each line by the spaces between the characters returned, then created a matrix by calling `rbind` on each row... which we then translated into a data frame.